# How to make soft-boiled eggs without breaking them?

Tags: eggs, boiling

Here's the difficulty:

If I put the eggs in a pot with cold water, then I can't reliably control how they cook. There are too many factors: amount of water, pot size, heat setting, etc.

If I put them in already boiling water, then I can get good results by controlling only the timing. The problem is that too often the eggs will crack from the heat shock.

---

I tried placing the eggs in warm water (from the tap) for 5 minutes so they wouldn't be fridge cold, and also laying them gently in the pot with a spoon, but sometimes they still crack. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Sneftel The two suggestions there are: 1. put them in cold water 2. lower them with a spoon. I explained why I cannot do 1. and that I already do 2.

Comment: There are, in fact, a great many more suggestions there. In any case, please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253924/what-to-do-when-the-question-you-want-to-ask-is-a-duplicate .

Comment: Please do not vandalise your post.